# Concurrency issues when using a member variable for caching in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching, concurrency, static

I'm using a static member to cache some data and I *believe* I'm having some kind of concurrency issue when the cached data is first populated. This problem is sporadic and seems to follow the recycling of the app pool (though often times there will not be a problem).

Initially my _CachedData member is null. When the FindAll() method is called it will use the cached data when _CachedData isn't null, otherwise it will load the data from the database. The _CachedData member is set to null whenever an insert, update, or delete is performed to the data, though this should never happen when the application is first loaded after an app pool recycle.

The error that I'm getting is an object reference error when I'm adding a TestClass object to result from _CachedData. I just don't see how this is possible since I'm performing a null check on _CachedData before I enter the for each loop.

```
Public Class TestClass

    Private Shared _CachedData As Collection(Of TestClass) = Nothing

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Shared Function FindAll() As Collection(Of Content.TestClass)
        Dim result As New Collection(Of TestClass)()

        If _CachedData IsNot Nothing Then
            ' retrieve from cache
            For Each tc As TestClass In _CachedData
                result.Add(CType(tc.MemberwiseClone(), TestClass))
            Next
        Else
            result = GetFromDatabase()

            ' save to cache
            _CachedData = New Collection(Of TestClass)()
            SyncLock _CachedData
                ' make sure the cache wasn't populated while we were aquiring the lock
                If _CachedData.Count = 0 Then
                    For Each tc As TestClass In result
                        _CachedData.Add(CType(tc.MemberwiseClone(), TestClass))
                    Next
                End If
            End SyncLock
        End If

        Return result
    End Function
```

faf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you should not actually be locking on the object itself, as you will be making changes to that object.  You should update your code as such:

```
Private Shared _CachedData As Collection(Of TestClass) = Nothing
Private Shared ReadOnly _CachedDataLock As Object = New Object()

Public Shared Function FindAll() As Collection(Of Content.TestClass)
    Dim result As New Collection(Of TestClass)()

    If _CachedData IsNot Nothing Then
        ' retrieve from cache, using a local instance to avoid race-conditions
        Dim localCachedData As Collection(Of TestClass) = _CachedData
        For Each tc As TestClass In localCachedData 
            result.Add(CType(tc.MemberwiseClone(), TestClass))
        Next
    Else
        result = GetFromDatabase()

        ' save to cache
        SyncLock _CachedDataLock
            ' make sure the cache wasn't populated while we were aquiring the lock
            If _CachedData Is Nothing Then
                _CachedData = New Collection(Of TestClass)()
                For Each tc As TestClass In result
                    _CachedData.Add(CType(tc.MemberwiseClone(), TestClass))
                Next
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Whoops, my bad on the locking. I'm not sure I understand how using a local instance avoids a race condition. Since you're not copying/cloning _CachedData, isn't localCachedData just a reference to the same data in memory?

Comment: That is correct, but when you reassign _CachedData (whether to null or New Collection) it changes the place in memory to which _CachedData points, but leaves the actual data alone but alive. Since the old data now has no pointer to it, the garbage collector comes along and eventually frees it up completely. If you point a local variable at that same memory, however, then it will be guaranteed to remain alive during this operation, regardless of how _CachedData is pointed.

Comment: We've gone a week without any problems so it looks like this resolved the issue. Thank you for your help, Mike!